# .execute('INSERT ...') does not actually insert data into table

Tags: python, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, sql-insert, psycopg2

**warning**: *brain fart imminent*

I've been at this for a bit now, and I'm guessing this is just a "I'm tired, can't get it through my head" type of issue so I'm hoping you will break this down for me..

I'll explain this backwards because it makes more sense..

I verify the contents of my table by doing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(time) AS UNIQUE_DATES FROM reports;
```

I'm expecting:

```
2014-06-17
2014-06-16
```

But `17` is missing..
So naturally I check my `query_string` by doing:

```
import psycopg2
database = psycopg2.connect(dbname=database, user=user, password=password, database=database)
cursor = database.cursor()
query_string = b"INSERT INTO reports (time) VALUES " + b','.join(cursor.mogrify('(%s)', value) for value in values) + b';')
print(query_string)
cursor.execute(query_string)
```

resulting in:

```
b"INSERT INTO reports(time) VALUES ('2014-06-17 10:00:08'),('2014-06-17 14:00:05');"
```

And no error messages.
And lo and behold.. if query:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

The `INSERT` shows up. (all tho be it at random times considering how fast that query would fly by into `<IDLE>` state.. but it's there)

But then again, it's not in the database.. How is this possible?
If i take the command and execute it in `psql` on my own sure enough it's inserted..

It makes no sense.. It would make sense if another PID was actually performing executions on the database, which i can't really say there is because again that last `SELECT` shows no active sessions, they're all idle..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **commit** the transaction:

```
connection.commit()
```

See the [Transactions control section](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#transactions-control) of the psycopg2 documentation.

`psql` operates in a different transaction mode; it auto-commits all statements. From the [`psql` documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html):

> `AUTOCOMMIT`
>   When on (the default), each SQL command is automatically committed upon successful completion. To postpone commit in this mode, you must enter a `BEGIN` or `START TRANSACTION SQL` command. When off or unset, SQL commands are not committed until you explicitly issue `COMMIT` or `END`.

Comment: Wow... Yup, i knew i had a brainfart somewhere haha. Love you dude, you're always around to help us less fortunate :) Cheers! This happned during a replacement of `py-postgresql` to `psycopg2`, must have accidently removed the commit.. again, such a brainfart..